# Caching the response to an external web service in hapi.js

Tags: node.js, redis, hapi.js

Im building a web app in hapi.js. Im pretty new to hapi.js so may not be following the framework correctly. But here is what I intend to do. 
Create a hapi route which will use one of the route params to make a series of web service calls to an external host. These calls need to be done in series.
I am currently using axios to make the calls and chaining them with 
.then().then() etc.
I would like to cache these responses to a redis store. I read up on the hapi caching examples of using catbox and hapi "server.methods" feature but not sure how they could be applied to a promise based call chain that I have currently. Is there something wrong with my thinking.

Answer (score 0):

Catbox the caching module used by hapi does not support promises as stated [here](https://github.com/hapijs/catbox/pull/161), maybe open an issue on Github or ask a question on [gitter](https://gitter.im/hapijs/hapi) or on [Github](https://github.com/hapijs/discuss) user forum to see what other users are doing.